# git, how to deal with branches where code is executing

Tags: git

I do a bunch of data analysis for my work. Allot of the time this requires me to execute code that can take hours. While the code is still executing, i want to be able to branch of the code and develop the code further. I may also would want to execute slight different branches in parallel. The problem with this is that it basically requires me to copy the code of a branch to a fresh directory so that my changes does not effect the execution of the mother branch, or so that output files of different branches running in parallel are not overwritten. Obviously, without any version control, dealing with all theses versions and their changes is a pain.

Lately I have started to use git, and it serves me well until i run into situations as explained above. I don't have much experience using external repositories (pull/push), but I suspect this could be solved using local external repositories.
How would you deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Just clone your repo.  You can then push and pull between the main repo and your clone.  Take a look at `git clone`, `git push` and `git pull`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options: You can have a local "master" repository, and then a bunch of satellite "client" repositories set up with that master repo as their remote, or you can simply have a bunch of local repositories all pointing at the real remote.

As I'm sure you know how to do the latter (a bunch of `git clone`s from different directories), here are instructions for setting up the former:

Clone the remote. This will be your aggregation point, or "master" repository. It's better to make it bare (having no working tree) to avoid confusion:

```
git clone --bare ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git repo.git
```

Then set up multiple clients to that one:

```
git clone file:///path/to/local/repo.git
```

Each one can be on its own branch and do its own thing. When you make changes to one of the clients, do a `git push` to push to the aggregation point, and then from the aggregation point you can do a `git push` to the server. From other clients you will need to do `git fetch` to pull new changes in that you've pushed from other clients.

Comment: If the plan is to push to the aggregation point, it'll be much easier if the OP makes it a bare repository with `git clone --bare`

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the answer, it is standard practice to suffix bare repository directories with `.git` to easily identify them. It also makes sense because the whole thing is a `.git` directory, rather than simply containing one.

Comment: @adymitruk I never said it was a good idea, I was just giving the solution to the specific problem he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up my build process to copy the binaries to a separate location outside the source folder, and set up the environment so that output files are also written to a separate location. Keep the source tree clear of generated data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute in a separate folder.

```
git archive | tar
```

or something similar. You are then free to continue working in your repo.

Cloning is not a good idea as you will be scattered in your reflog and rerere history. Symlink back to the repo for specific files if you need.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, this seems good for exporting only the version controlled files, so that i can place them elsewhere, but it does nothing in terms of version control of the different "branches" I will create.